# table with resizable columns, should have columns added / removed dynamically & sortable values with in columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have requirement to develop a list display which should be a table with resizable columns, should have columns added / removed dynamically & sortable values with in columns.

The columns are needed to be added and removed dynamically. Initially some columns can be displayed by default. Later additional columns can be added by choosing from a drop down for columns selection.

Initially one column is sorted by ascending order.

We are using HTML 5 with angularjs on UI layer.

I tried searching for plugin or javascript libraries but none of them provided all the features which matches all our requirement.

Can you please provide a good suggestion of how to go about this situation?

Comment: you want rows to be added/removed dynamically or columns? Just confirming!

Comment: yes. I want them to be added and removed dynamically. Initially some columns can be displayed by default. Later additional columns can be added by choosing from a drop down for columns selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-grid and customize it accordingly. However, we have used jqx library since it has many other items including grid-

Link for grid-
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(arctic)

For adding column dynamically, you can update the column definition in runtime which will help you to add/delete columns.
All other features you mentioned are included as features by jqx itself.